# Sorting lists by date and then order by latest

Tags: c#, sorting, list

I have a list and would like to sort by date then order by latest date first.

The code below sorts by date:

```
allFeeds.Sort(delegate(SimplifiedFeedItem p1, SimplifiedFeedItem p2)
                    { return p1.PublishDate.CompareTo(p2.PublishDate); });

                    allFeeds.ForEach(delegate(SimplifiedFeedItem p)
                    { // display list});
```

How do I then order it by the latest date first (its ordering by the oldest date first currently)?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the sign that is returned from `DateTime.CompareTo`:

```
allFeeds.Sort(delegate(SimplifiedFeedItem p1, SimplifiedFeedItem p2)
                { return -p1.PublishDate.CompareTo(p2.PublishDate); });
```

You can make this cleaner using a lambda expression:

```
allFeeds.Sort((p1, p2) => -p1.PublishDate.CompareTo(p2.PublishDate));
```

Comment: @Jason what is p1 and p1, can you give complete code with p1 and p2 definition?

Comment: `p1` and `p2` are parameters in the lambda expression; they are akin  to method parameters. It's as if I had defined `int f(SimplifiedFeedItem p1, SimplifiedFeedItem p2) { return -p1.PublishDate.CompareTo(p2.PublishDate); }` but instead, the lambda expression allows us to do that inline.